# Find all records matching attribute on self association (SQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following models

```
Shipment (id, product_id, ...)
Product (id, product_id, some_attribute:boolean, ...)
```

Where a shipment belongs to a product and a product has many shipments. Furthermore, a product can be a subproduct of another product through a self reference (`product_id`)

I want to find all the shipments for which the `some_attribute` on the product at the top of the self reference chain is true.

For example, in this example

```
shipment1 (id = 1, product_id = 1)
shipment2 (id = 2, product_id = 2)

product1 (id = 1, product_id = 3, some_attribute = false)
product2 (id = 2, product_id = 4, some_attribute = false)
product3 (id = 3, product_id = null, some_attribute = false)
product4 (id = 4, product_id = null, some_attribute = true)
```

only `shipment2` should be returned, because it's product line goes like `p2->p4`, where `some_attribute` is true for `p4`

Much appreciated

EDIT:

For clarity, the product chain can arbitrarily long, but in practice, it's usually around 2-3 links

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that your reference chain can be longer then in your example?

Comment: yes it can be an arbitrary length, but in practice it's usually around 2-3 links

Comment: I think you're going to need to explore the `WITH RECURSIVE` version of CTEs: https://truongtx.me/2014/02/28/tree-structure-query-with-postgresql/ http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-with.html

Comment: Yeah I looked at that but was unable to make it work, if you could provide an example it would be great

Comment: I've never used it. My first link in my previous comment has examples. If you add your attempt to your question text, I'll see if I can help with that.